# How to extract the date from the string pattern in perl

Tags: perl

How do I extract date `Simple_Invoice_Report.Summary.20150701000000.csv` from this string in perl?

i.e. `20150701`

Can you please help me out.

Comment: Please show the code you are having problems with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to extract the data from the above string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = q{Simple_Invoice_Report.Summary.20150701000000.csv};
if($string =~ m#.(\d{8})\d+.csv#g){
    print $1;
}
```

Output: 20150701

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is a regular expression match. Assuming your date is *always* the first 8 digits in your string:

```
my ( $date ) = ( $string =~ m/(\d{8})/ );
```

If it's more complicated than that, you'll need to be a bit more specific.